# Extracting end of filename in bash script

Tags: bash

Within my backup script, I'd like to only keep 7 days worth of backups (tried using logrotate for this and  it worked perfectly, but I ran into issues with the timing of cron.daily and how it affected the "dateext"). I'm running into problems using parameter expansion to extract the date from the filenames.

Here are some examples of some of the files

- foo.bar.tar.gz-20120904
- bar.baz.tar.gz-20120904
- ...

Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/foo/"
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
keepDays=7
keepSeconds=$(date -d "-$keepDays day" +%s)

for f in $path"*"; do
  fileSeconds=$(date -d ${f##*-} +%s)
  if [ $fileSeconds -lt $keepSeconds ]
    then
        rm $f
  fi
done
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
date: extra operand `/foo/foo.bar.tar.gz-20120904'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [cdarke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736308/cdarke) says, remove the quotes around the `*` in the `for` loop:

```
for f in ${path}/*; do
```

What happens is that the shell executing `date` gets '/foo/*' and expands that into a list of file names (more than one) and then uses `${f##*-}` on part of the list, and `date` is called with multiple names, and objects.

You'd see this if you ran with `bash -x your-script.sh`, for instance.  When something mysterious goes on, the first step is to make sure you know what the shell is doing.  Adding `echo "$f"` or `echo $f` in the loop would help you understand — though you'd get two different answers.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes around the `*`, that prevents globbing:

```
for f in ${path}*; do
```

(the `{ }` are not strictly required here, but make it easier to read)

Not part of the question, but the Bourne shell syntax `[ $fileSeconds -lt $keepSeconds ]` could be written as `(( $fileSeconds < $keepSeconds ))` which is possibly safer.